# i am running ubuntu 22.04 and i cant update

Tags: command-line, 22.04

when i type

```
sudo apt update
```

it gives my an error

```
Err:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy Release.
404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy `Release' does not have a Release file.`
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: At this time, https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu has not updated their packages for Jammy. Therefore you must remove that PPA from your sources list (at least until they create a Jammy repository).

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 22.04 ships with Gnome 42. It looks like you have a PPA repository for Gnome 3 enabled. Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) was the most recent Ubuntu release supported by that repository, so you no longer have a need for it on your system.

To fix that error, you need to remove that repository, which can be done with the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

For further reading on that repository, see the [GNOME3 PPA End of Life Announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-gnome/2017-March/004229.html).

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 4612 (aptd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: In your case, the process with the lock is 4612, but to actually search, use `ps aux | grep "[a]pt"`. Use `kill 4612` to kill that process. If the ps command no longer returns applicable results, it should be safe to remove the lock file (`rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`). Assuming you're not running as root, you will need to use sudo with those commands. Alternatively, just try rebooting and the problem may resolve itself.